# Add a Count property to custom class in C#

Tags: c#, class, count

So I have a custom class (ie, MyClass), which I then use to declare an array.  How would I add a '.Count' property to my custom class to get the size of the array?

Thank you.

```
static void Main()
{
    MyClass[] test = new MyClass[2];
    test[0].str = "Hello";
    test[1].str = "World";

    Console.WriteLine("Count : " + test.Count);
}


class MyClass
{
    public string str;
}
```

Comment: That's not a custom class; it's an array of your custom class. And it already has a `Length` property.

Comment: try test.Length instead of test.Count

Comment: I get an 'The member `System.Array.Length' cannot be used as method or delegate' compile error

Comment: `test.Length` should work with the posted code. It think you tried `test.Length()`

Comment: Use MyClass[] test = new MyClass()[2]; else your code will not compile

Comment: Is this what you want? http://ideone.com/rxRoW

Comment: test.Length did work, thank you Henk.
and thanks Nikhil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made an array, so it should already have a test.Length property.

Comment: strange I wasn't able to access .Length

Comment: I get an 'The member `System.Array.Length' cannot be used as method or delegate'

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not initialising correctly, it should be: MyClass[] test = new MyClass()[2];

Answer (score 1):

Your custom class is not aware of the fact that it's in an array. Therefore you can not get a count of the number of objects in your array since only Main() knows how many object the array contains.

Answer (score 0):

First your code should be like

```
MyClass[] test = new MyClass()[2];
```

second if you want to know how many instances of your class has been generated. create a

```
public static int Count;
```

and increment its property in the constructor of your class like

```
public MyClass()
{
    Count++;
}
```

If you want to know the number of instances then just write

```
MessageBox.Show(Myclass.Count.ToString());
```